# How to add "complex" shadow to a view in android?

Tags: android, view, shadow

Im trying to figure out if there's a way to add a shadow (complex one, not linear) to
a view in android?

here's an image of the requested result:

[image]

as you can see, in the cornes the shadow is strongr and as we go to the middle, the shadow becomes lighter.

Is there a way to do this without using an image below the view?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function which easily do this. You would have do invent a program just to draw this effect. However using 9-patch png it can be done with a streachable image: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html